# Is there any way to reduce the cost of deactivate_slab.isra.82 in alloc_skb on Debian

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I have a UDP heavy workflow which bottlenecks due to `deactivate_slab.isra.82` called by `__alloc_skb` (15+% of CPU time). The alloc method seems to be being called inside the Intel card driver most frequently (I assume for the RX path) but also by my send syscalls.

I can only push about 1.1Gbps on a 10G server due to this bottleneck, I'm wondering if there are any kernel parameters I can tweak to reduce this overhead, perhaps something to expand the size of free lists for SKBs so that the kernel-malloc path isn't hit as frequently.

I already noticed that `slub_debug` is enabled by default on Debian which was slowing my application even further (from 850Mbps to 1.1Gbps).

Answer (score 0):

This was my misunderstanding in the slub_debug option, the correct way to turn it off is "slub_debug=-", " slub_debug=off" disabled the slab debug check but not all the debugging code.

After properly disabling the debug mode I see significant performance gains for my UDP heavy workloads and there is no obvious single kernel function causing a bottleneck anymore.